# In what way is "are us" used?

Tags: idioms

In what way is "are us" used? Like: what does "toys are us" mean.. Or what does "heavy weights are us" mean?

Does "are us" always refer to several people? Or can one also use it when referring just to oneself?

Comment: There's a clue in the ‘Я’ that we might be dealing with non-standard English.

Answer (score 5):

It's invariably used in fairly lame "witty trading name/slogan" contexts, which as others have pointed out, all derive from the original "Toys R Us". The noun that precedes it is always something "we" (not "us") specialise in supplying.

I can easily imagine someone in a group of enthusiastic [drinking buddies](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drinking%20buddy) saying, for example *"[Alkies](http://dictionary.reference.com/slang/alkie) are us!"*, but after Googling **"are us" -shopping** and leafing through several pages of results, I have to say it's not exactly a commonplace idiomatic usage outside commercial contexts (that's to say, I didn't come across a single instance of anything 'non-commerical').

Grammatically speaking it's, well, not. You can say, for example, *"We are human"* in standard English, and *"Human are we"* in [Yoda-speak](http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/), but *"Human[s] are us"* is never going to cut it.

Comment: Grammatically speaking it's fine: Toys (subject, plural) are (verb, plural) us (object, plural). Your "human" example doesn't apply because "human" is being used as an adjective in that context—that example's a totally different construction than "Toys are us".

Comment: @andyvn22: I've no idea what you mean by "Grammatically speaking it's fine". The closest comparable usage I can think of is *"Knock, knock!", "Who's there?", "**It's us**"* (subject:singular, object:plural). To my mind, if there's a form of words that in principle *ought* to be commonly used, but in fact never actually is (except by way of echoing the quirky *Toys R Us* tradename), it seems reasonable to say that (idiomatically speaking) it must be "ungrammatical". Grammar describes what people say; it's not a pre-existing set of rules allowing forms no-one actually uses.

Comment: We are using the word "grammar" slightly differently then; in any case, my meaning was that while "us" as the object of "are" is not a common usage, it is not obviously nonsensical like your example is. It's interpretable as similar to "toys are dogs", whereas "human are us" is not (as there is no subject in the whole sentence)!

Comment: @andyvn22: Ah, right. I see what you mean now. You're focussing on the *we/us, subject/object* aspect of grammaticality here. Interestingly, actual speakers don't seem to care much about that in some contexts (they're often just as happy with *"It is I"* as with *"It is me"*). On the other hand, I bet [*This is us*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2515086/), which has a truly dismal 3.8 stars on IMDB, would have got an even worse rating if it had been *This is we* or (God forbid! :) *These are us*.

Comment: There are quite a few contexts where “are us” would end up, though none is perhaps common. “They are us” is quite grammatical, for instance, as is “The only ones affected are us”. It would just be more natural in most cases to make switch subject and complement as part of the general tendency for pronouns to prefer occupying the least marked element in a sentence. @andyvn There is no such thing as “the object of _are_”: the verb _be_ does not take objects.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Human are us* is not going to work because the verb would have to agree with the subject and the subject is uncountable.  *Who's the boss?* *The boss is him, over there* seems fine.

Comment: We have seen the enemy and they are us .https://humorinamerica.wordpress.com/2014/05/19/the-morphology-of-a-humorous-phrase/

Answer (score 1):

If you accept the first of the following then the rest follow in a similar pattern:

- It is me
- It is us
- They are us
- Toys are us

So the last is a possible response to the question "Who are toys?" but the shop's name is simply saying "You can buy toys here, as they are what we do."

Comment: They are **not** all part of the same pattern.  “It is me / us.” is a special construction that uses the *empty “it”*.  Or do you think it’s normal to say, “Henry is me.”?

Comment: @Pitarou "Henry is me" works in response to "I just got a letter from some idiot called Henry" and usually produces profuse embarrassment and apologies

Comment: But "Toys are us" is semantically quite different. "They are us" and "Henry is me" are both identifying the referent of an existing expression whose referent is hitherto unknown.  "Toys are us" is making a substantive claim, and arguably not one of identity.

Comment: @Henry That’s not the English I speak! I’d say either “That’s me!” or “I’m Henry.” Maybe the coiner of “Toys Я Us” spoke a dialect similar to yours?

Comment: @Pitarou If someone asks *Who's Henry?* Then *Henry's me!* is a fine answer. Just a bit more unusual than *I 'm Henry* which requires contrastive stress on the *I*.

Answer (score 1):

It clearly isn’t standard English grammar and, as others have pointed out, this form is hardly ever used except in shop names.

My best guess is that the founder started with “We are Toys”, and then experimented with ways of moving the word “Toys” to the beginning of the sentence to make it more prominent.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a grammatical nightmare, but let‘s just say it's a brand derivate and in popular slang it has found its place.
The ARE, does it refer to the plural form of the subject or the object?
Let‘s say in pop culture... would it be wrong to say Apocalypse are us, meaning that the one thing human kind specializes in is bringing on the end of the world.
Apocalypse IS us does sound even worse.

Answer (score -3):

"Toys/they are us" is NOT grammatically correct; 'us' in this case is a predicate nominative connected by the copula/linking verb form of to be and should therefore be 'we'; also “The only ones affected are we”...."we are the only ones affected". It just may sound strange to us because of pervasive, informal (incorrect) usage (thanks to the help of such store names!)

Comment: This is not only outdated, prescriptive nonsense (the oblique case has been used for predicative arguments for centuries, and in current English, the subject case is _much_ more likely to be ungrammatical than the oblique case: “That's I on the right there”, for example, is utterly ungrammatical, as evidenced by the fact that _no one ever says it_), but also factually incorrect: _us_ can never, under any circumstances, be a predicate nominative, since it's _not a nominative_.

Answer (score -5):

In the store name, it is not "are" but a backward letter R.
[image]

Comment: -1: the name of the store is a clear pun on "toys are us", so much that even on their website you can see it spelled are Toys"R"Us.

Comment: So much so that the *ARE*  was shortened to *R* when the founder of the company opened a store and the original name could not fit on the store's sign. Source [answers.com](http://www.answers.com/topic/toys-r-us)

Comment: That’s really not helpful.  It’s perfectly clear that the ‘Я’ is meant to mean ‘are’.